Advanced Custom Fields: recognize what I need Pro for
I'm a total newbie in wordpress, but inherited this project that we start to self-host. It's made by a contractor and uses a bunch of licensed pro versions of plugins.
I'm trying to trim the fat so we don't have to buy the same bunch of licenses, and narrowed it down to where things start to break if the site doesn't have Pro version of ACF.
Can you give any tips how I could see what Pro features are required, and if I could convert the site to using just Free version or something native instead? When I replace Pro with Free, everything just goes blank and I don't see any errors.
The site is a simple 2-pager but has some complex layout things going on.

Okay, after fiddling around I found references to ACF functions in a custom theme that gave error messages when debugging was enabled, and then found Pro field types from their website
